# How channel work in using channel to find prime number problem?

Tags: go, channel

I have an approach to solve the find prime number problem using Go like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Generate natural seri number: 2,3,4,...
func GenerateNatural() chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 2; ; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

// Filter: delete the number which is divisible by a prime number to find prime number
func PrimeFilter(in <-chan int, prime int) chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for {
            if i := <-in; i%prime != 0 {
                out <- i
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    ch := GenerateNatural()
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        prime := <-ch

        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", i+1, prime)
        ch = PrimeFilter(ch, prime)

    }
}
```

I have no idea what happen in this approach:

- I know that can not print the content of channel without interrupt: [Can not print content of channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647393/how-to-print-contents-of-channel-without-changing-it)
- Size of channel: Default buffer channel size is `1`, that mean:

> By default channels are unbuffered, which states that they will only
> accept sends (chan <-) if there is a corresponding receive (<- chan)
> which are ready to receive the sent value

I can not image how above Go program run!

Could anybody please help to show me the step by step flow of above Go program for first 10 number or so?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking someone to step through this code with you, explaining each line?

Comment: @Flimzy No, I understand the main purpose and function but I can not image how the 
unbuffered channel send and receive which value (go routine is not run in sequence).

Comment: Both GenerateNatural and PrimeFilter each start goroutines which run concurrently, one is sending, one receiving and the main goroutine is running too. Note that this is a pretty complicated example and it helps to use paper and pencil to see what is happening.

Comment: This is a pretty convoluted example. In both functions, `go func(){...}()` creates an anonymous goroutine and runs it asynchronously, then returns the channel. `PrimeFilter` returns a channel which will receive numbers not divisible by a certain candidate. Since `ch = PrimeFilter(ch, prime)` assigns the new channel instance to `ch` in each iteration, this also means that `prime := <-ch` always reads the first value from a different channel each time.

Comment: `ch = PrimeFilter(ch, prime)` @Groo You 're right and that why I can't image the flow even when I print the i (iterator)

Comment: Can someone explain why Go playground shows two values passed to channel `ch` from the goroutine in `GenerateNatural` ? I'd assume an unbuffered channel would block until the first value written to it gets read. My debug prints show two values for `i`, before the `fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", i+1, prime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty convoluted example. In both functions, `go func(){...}()` creates an anonymous goroutine and runs it asynchronously, then returns the channel which will receive values from the goroutine. `PrimeFilter` returns a channel which will receive numbers not divisible by a certain candidate.

The idea is that `prime := <-ch` always takes the first element from the channel. So, to visualize the flow:

1. `GenerateNatural()` starts by sending numbers 2, 3, 4... to `ch`.
2. First loop iteration:

   a. `prime := <-ch` reads the first (prime) number `2`.

   b. `PrimeFilter(ch, 2)` then continues receiving the rest of the numbers (`3`, `4`, `5`, ...), and sends numbers not divisible by `2` to the output channel. So, channel returned by `PrimeFilter(ch, 2)` will receive numbers (`3`, `5`, `7`, ...).

   c. `ch = PrimeFilter(ch, prime)` in the main function now **replaces** the local `ch` variable with the output of `PrimeFilter(ch, 2)` from the previous step.
3. Second loop iteration:

   a. `prime := <-ch` reads the first (prime) number from the current `ch` instance (this first number is `3`).

   b. `PrimeFilter(ch, 3)` then continues receiving the (already filtered) numbers, except for the first one (so, `5`, `7`, `9`, ...), and sends numbers not divisible by `3` to the output channel. So, channel returned by `PrimeFilter(ch, 2)` will receive numbers `5`, `7`, `11`, ..., because `9` is divisible by `3`.

   c. `ch = PrimeFilter(ch, prime)` in the main function now **replaces** the local `ch` variable with the output of `PrimeFilter(ch, 3)` from the previous step.
4. ...

Comment: So, the main Go program will replace the ch channel after every iterator, and do not close any channel, right? After you illustrate some steps, I got the idea of this approach. Tks

Comment: @ThoQuach: yes, each new channel creates a closure which references the previous channel, so by the time you reach 100th prime, you have 100 goroutines running in parallel, each receiving the data sent by the previous one.

Comment: This program is used to illustrate the different approach to solve the find prime number problem, but I see is is quite complicated and use compute resources in a in an inefficient way